# How to delete the second consecutive/occurrence of duplicate rows from pandas dataframe with condition by python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My dataframe looks like as follows

```
import pandas as pd
uid=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
pid=[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,7,7,8,7,7,7,6,6,7,6,1,5,1,1,2,2,2,1]
sid=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
df=pd.DataFrame({'uid':uid, 'pid':pid,'sid':sid})

print(df)


     uid  pid  sid
0     1    1    1
1     1    1    1
2     1    1    1
3     1    2    1
4     1    2    1
5     1    1    1
6     1    1    1
7     1    7    2
8     1    7    2
9     1    8    2
10    1    7    2
11    1    7    2
12    1    7    2
13    2    6    3
14    2    6    3
15    2    7    3
16    2    6    3
17    3    1    4
18    3    5    4
19    3    1    4
20    3    1    5
21    3    2    5
22    3    2    5
23    3    2    5
24    3    1    5
```

Now I want to delete the second consecutive/occurrence values (1 and 7) for pid column at 5th,6th rows and 10th,11th,12 th rows based on uid and sid. I used the following code as

```
df['start'] = df['pid'] != df['pid'].shift()
df['start'] = df['pid'] != df['pid'].shift()
df['group'] = df.groupby('pid')['start'].cumsum()
result = df.loc[df['group'] == 1]
print(result)
```

I got the output as

```
     uid  pid  sid  start  group
0     1    1    1   True    1.0
1     1    1    1  False    1.0
2     1    1    1  False    1.0
3     1    2    1   True    1.0
4     1    2    1  False    1.0
7     1    7    2   True    1.0
8     1    7    2  False    1.0
9     1    8    2   True    1.0
13    2    6    3   True    1.0
14    2    6    3  False    1.0
18    3    5    4   True    1.0
```

In the above output it deletes the second consecutive values (1 and 7) for pid column at 5th,6th rows and 10th,11th,12th rows. But it also deletes for uid=2 and uid=3. I want to keep the pid(6,7) values for uid=2 at rows 13th,14th,15th. Also for uid=3 and sid=4 I want to keep the pid(1,5) values at 17th,18th rows. Then  for uid=3 and sid=5 I want to keep the pid(1,2) values at 20th,21th,22th,23th rows. Now I want to delete the duplicate values of pid(1) for uid=1 and sid=1 at 5th,6th rows, then pid(7) for uid=1,sid=2 at 10th,11th,12 rows, then pid(6) for uid=2,sid=3 at 16th row, then pid(1) for uid=3,sid=4 at 19th row, then pid(1) for uid=3,sid=5 at 24th row as below

```
     uid  pid  sid
0     1    1    1
1     1    1    1
2     1    1    1
3     1    2    1
4     1    2    1
7     1    7    2
8     1    7    2
9     1    8    2
13    2    6    3
14    2    6    3
15    2    7    3
17    3    1    4
18    3    5    4
20    3    1    5
21    3    2    5
22    3    2    5
23    3    2    5
```

How to achieve this? Guide me to get the above output. Thanks in advance.

**Note: The 2nd consecutive values not always consecutive sometimes it may be single is nothing but 2nd occurrence of pid values.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. This can be achieved using `groupby` function and keeping only the top 2 rows.

**Code:**

```
df.groupby(['pid', 'sid']).head(2)
```

**Output:**

```
    uid pid sid
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
2   1   2   1
3   1   2   1
6   1   7   2
7   1   7   2
8   1   8   2
9   1   8   2
12  2   7   3
13  2   7   3
16  3   1   4
17  3   1   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much naveen for your valuable suggestion. Extremely sorry I did one mistake in my question. Like uid=1 , for uid=2 and uid=3 also has some other pid values after consecutive values. Let consider uid=2 and rows between 13th and 14th as well as uid=3 and rows between 17th and 18th there will be some pid values like (5 or 10). Then only it will be second consecutive values for pid based on uid and sid. Also the consecutive values not fixed with 2 rows. It may be any number of rows. So consider this situation and guide me the solution. Thanks..

Comment: it would be helpful if you can add those extra values in your questions to see how I can group them. Can you edit your questions accordingly?

Comment: df.groupby(['pid', 'sid']) code works fine except row 20th and 24th. Guide me to resolve it. Thanks..

Comment: Using this code df.groupby(['pid', 'sid']) for above dataframe, In the 19th row uid=1, pid=1,sid=4 and in 20th row uid=1, pid=1,sid=5. In this situation 20th row pid=1 is the first occurrence for sid=5 and 24th row pid=1 is the 2nd occurrence for sid=5 .. actually 24th row only want to delete, but 20th row is deleted.. So guide me how to retain the value like this scenario..  Thanks..